# Add text under "Place Order" button at WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add some text under the "Place Order" button at WooCommerce checkout.

I'm using the `woocommerce_review_order_after_submit` hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', 'add_after_checkout_button' );

function add_after_checkout_button() {
echo '<p>By clicking on the purchase button, you agree to our Terms of Service and Privacy Policy</p>';
}
```

Result (screenshot): https://ibb.co/F38bxDf

Could someone please help me edit this code to:

- Add some space at the top (between the text and the "Place Order"
  button)
- Center align the text
- Turn "Terms of Service" and "Privacy Policy" into clickable links
- Decrease the line-height of the text
- Decrease the font size

Is there a way to give this text a CSS class so I can control the styling of it with custom CSS? Or is possible to somehow type the custom CSS in the code snippet itself?

**EDIT:**

I've got 2 pieces of code.

**Nr 1:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', 'add_after_checkout_button' );

function add_after_checkout_button() {

echo '<p class="text-under-place-order">By clicking on the purchase button, you agree to our <a href="https://www.exampledomain.com/terms-of-service/">Terms of Service</a> and <a href="https://www.exampledomain.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a></p>';
}
```

and

**Nr 2:**

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5e15d2f246.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        SSL encrypted payment
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <i class="fas fa-undo"></i>
        100% money-back guarantee
    </div>
</div>
```

Code snippet **Nr 1** solves my initial question.

Code snippet **Nr 2** is an addition to display "encrypted payment" and "money-back guarantee" above the text as per my request in the comments.

I don't know how to merge these 2 pieces of code into 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a class like this:

```
function add_after_checkout_button() {
    echo '<p class="yourClassName">By clicking on the purchase button, you agree to our Terms of Service and Privacy Policy</p>';
}
```

Or use css inline like this:

```
function add_after_checkout_button() {
    echo '<p style="padding-top: 10px;">By clicking on the purchase button, you agree to our Terms of Service and Privacy Policy</p>';
}
```

To turn the text into links just use a `<a href="link">Terms and Service</a>` tag inside, just like you already did with the `<p>`.

**EDIT:**
HTML and CSS code to add an "encrypted payment" and "money-back guarantee" as requested in the comments:

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5e15d2f246.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
        SSL encrypted payment
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <i class="fas fa-undo"></i>
        100% money-back guarantee
    </div>
</div>

.row {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
}

.column {
    flex: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Hi @crossi100. Thank you for your answer, everything worked. I would also like to add something like this above the text: https://ibb.co/wNJH3YJ Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, @JOKKER. Have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/crossi100/pen/poNgbjN). I used fontawesome because they have both icons available in their free set. You can use any icon library you want though. You'll probably need to play around with the styles a bit for the correct text placement.

I'll also edit this code into the answer should the codepen become unavailable.

Comment: Where should the new HTML code snippet be placed in the previous code?

Comment: Hey @crossi100. Sorry to bother you but I can't seem to figure out how to merge the 2 pieces of code into 1. Could you please help me out? I'm getting errors trying to place the new HTML code in different places of the previous code snippet.

Comment: Sorry, somehow missed your first comment @JOKKER. I created a new [pen for that](https://codepen.io/crossi100/pen/abBdeje). I replaced the CSS classes with inline styles so you can just copy-paste the full html code into your echo (except for the script tag). You need to add the script tag to the head of your html. As you're using WordPress you should find dozens of tutorials on google explaining to you how you can add fontawesome. Please note that I'm no CSS expert either and I've just thrown some stuff together that looks okay-ish on one viewpoint. This probably needs some fine-tuning.

Comment: Sorry @crossi100 but I still don't get it. I had no issue with the CSS code. I even prefer to edit the style with custom CSS as I am a bit more familiar with it than with inline styling. I edited my original question to give you a better understanding of what I'm asking. I'm a beginner when it comes to coding. I don't know the correct order everything should be in. I have no idea what's an `echo` or `head of the html`. I would greatly appreciate if you could just merge the 2 pieces of code into 1.

Comment: Hey @crossi100. Sorry to bother you again but I still haven't figured out how to merge the 2 pieces of code into 1. Could you please take a look at my edited original question and help me out?

Comment: @JOKKER you need to add the html code to the echo like [here](https://3v4l.org/F4Kbt). If you can't see the icons then, you should google how to integrate font awesome into wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You should just add a class to your  tag `<p></p>` and style it in your style.css file in your child theme.
For the links, just add tags `<a href="your-link"></a>` around the words "Terms of Service" and "Privacy Policy"